# How to add gesture support in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using Bootstrap for a web app. I have a series of divs between which I navigate with  next/previous buttons. I would like to allow swipe gestures instead of button-based navigation where touch is available. What is the best way to go?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp

Comment: no, i haven't but this is exactly what i was looking for :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then here is your answer:
 Jquery mobile touch events:

[Documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp)

Comment: Good read on this [topic] (http://lazcreative.com/blog/adding-swipe-support-to-bootstrap-carousel-3-0/)